# Java nested for loop

Tags: java, loops

Here's what i don't understand as you can see my outer loop should only print 5 rows but when i add my inner loop it print 6 rows one blank and 5 0123 what happened here? why did my outer loop print 6 rows?

```
public static void main (String[] args) {


    int x;
    int y;

        for(x=1; x<=5; x++){
            System.out.println();
                for (y=0; y<4; y++){
                    System.out.print(y);
            }

        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    //dont need to declare variables here. they can be declared in loop like below
    for(int x=0; x<5; x++){
        System.out.println(); //this is called before inner loop, printing a blank line
            for (int y=0; y<4; y++){
                System.out.print(y); //print 0-3 
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to print a blank line after the inner loop place the `System.out.println()` after the inner loop.

Stepping through the code with a debugger should have been your first troubleshooting step here. You should also standardise your loop variable checks like I have done above.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing the loop does is output a newline.  Any characters printed in the `y` for loop after it appear on the next line.  So, this prints 5 newlines, each followed by the `y` characters on the next line.  The last iteration prints its characters on the 6th line, which follows the 5th newline character printed.

Move `System.out.println()` after the `y` `for` loop so it ends the line properly, after writing the characters.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the new line before the actual output. Move `System.out.println();` after the inner for loop:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int x;
    int y;

    for(x=1; x<=5; x++){
        for (y=0; y<4; y++){
            System.out.print(y);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
0123
0123
0123
0123
0123
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first instruction in your outer loop is

```
System.out.println();
```

which means you are moving cursor to next line (leaving first line empty).

Then

```
for (y=0; y<4; y++){
    System.out.print(y);
```

happens which is responsible for printing `0123` in that line.

Then again in next iteration of outer loop cursor is moved to next line and 0123 is printed.

Consider moving `System.our.println()` at the end of your outer loop. This way you will let inner loop print `0123` first, before moving cursor to next line.

Answer (score 0):

your outer loop first prints a blank line, then 0123 on the next
try

```
int x;
    int y;

        for(x=1; x<=5; x++){
                for (y=0; y<4; y++){
                    System.out.print(y);
            }
            System.out.println();

        }
```